# Grep for git branches starting with string

Tags: git, grep

I have the following branches:

```
dependabot/npm_and_yarn/types/jest-28.1.3
dependabot/pip/django-environ-0.9.0
test-dependabot/test
```

I want to grep the first two branches:

```
dependabot/npm_and_yarn/types/jest-28.1.3
dependabot/pip/django-environ-0.9.0
```

I've tried the following solutions but no luck:

- `git branch | grep dependabot/` - grabs all 3 branches
- `git branch | grep ^dependabot/` - grabs no branches

What is the correct grep regex for this use case? The string start character `^` doesn't seem to be working correctly here?

Comment: 'br' is not a git command, is it an alias for branch ?

Comment: Yes, just fixed that to make the question more clear

Comment: The output usually starts with two spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with a leading space before your branch name (you can have a leading `*` if it is the current branch)

`git branch|grep "\s\+dependabot/"`

More formal a line starting with an optional * then one or several spaces before your branch name

```
git branch|grep "^\*\?\s\+dependabot/"
```

Comment: Ended up going with this variation just in case there's no spaces before the branch name starts: `git branch | grep '^\*\?\s*dependabot/'`

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `git + grep`:

```bash
git branch | grep '^[*[:blank:]]*dependabot/'
```

`[[:blank:]]*` matches 0 or more whitespaces or `*` after matching line start with `^`

Comment: You can have a start at the beginning of the line if it is the current branch

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid `*` and use simple regex, I prefer `git for-each-ref`.

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads --format="%(refname:short)" | grep ^dependabot/
```

The `git for-each-ref` part is long, so make an alias once for all.

```
git config --global alias.brs 'for-each-ref refs/heads --format="%(refname:short)"'
```

Now it's more simple to filter branches.

```
git brs | grep ^dependabot/
```